# Father and Children One to Many Relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a Member  table for an organisation and some members are the children of some other members.  I want to link Fathers or Mothers with their child or children when the parent's details are pulled up.  I had this idea but it seems that will not work

```
public class IsParent
{
    [Key]
    public int PId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Parent")]
    public int MId { get; set; }
    public virtual Member Member { get; set; }    
    [DisplayName("Child")]
    public int MId { get; set; }
    public virtual Member Member { get; set; }    
}
```

Any Help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean to have the duplicate property names?

Comment: What I want to do is to have a parent Id and a child Id  taken from the member table. I might be doing it wrongly but the idea is to be able to associate a parent with their children who are all in  a common member table

Comment: _the idea is to be able to associate a parent with their children who are all in a common member table_. It looks like you're trying to set up (or are already in the process of setting up) navigation properties. Have a look at this tutorial - http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application. Once you have the navigation property setup (e.g. for the child) you'll be able to access it's primary key (id) and all of the other data stored in it. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the child and parent id are stored against the `Member` entity and you have the navigation property setup for `Member` in your `IsParent` entity (remove one of the duplicates as pointed out by Trey Gramann), you should be able to access the values you're after (e.g. in your controllers) like so:

```
int childID = IsParent.Member.ParentID; 
//Assuming your ParentID in the member entity is called `ParentID`

int parentID = IsParent.Member.ChildID; 
//Assuming your ParentID in the member entity is called `ChildID`
```

That's probably all you need to do. However, you may like to be able to access these properties from the `Member` navigation property for some reason - if so continue reading.

If you have set your `Member` entity up with navigation properties for both `Child` and `Parent`, you should be able to use something like the following to get the `Child` and `Parent` entities using regular object dot notation (here I'm assuming they are of the type `Person`, but you may have this set up differently):

```
Person child = IsParent.Member.Child;
Person parent = IsParent.Member.Parent;
```

If you want to cache these against the `IsParent` entity you could try this:

```
public class IsParent
{
    [Key]
    public int PId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("ParentID")]
    public int ParentID { 
           get {
               return Member.ParentID;
           }; 
           set {
               Member.ParentID = value;
           };
    }

    [DisplayName("ChildID")]
    public int ChildID {
           get {
               return Member.ChildID;
           }; 
           set {
               Member.ChildID = value;
           };
    }

    public virtual Member Member { get; set; }    
}
```

You could use a similar approach if you wanted to access the Child and Parent entities directly from `IsParent`:

```
   [DisplayName("Parent")]
    public Person Parent { 
           get {
               return Member.Parent;
           }; 
           set {
               Member.Parent = value;
           };
    }

    [DisplayName("Child")]
    public Person Child {
           get {
               return Member.Child;
           }; 
           set {
               Member.Child = value;
           };
    }
```

I have some concerns with this approach - I can't guarantee that the setting methods would work reliably (although I have used this approach in the past, I think this would depend on how you set up your repositories, possibly leading to unexpected behaviour). I also think you'd be better off just setting the navigation properties for Child and Parent on the Member entity and just accessing them the first way I showed you.

Can I strongly recommend you read this tutorial as I think this will clear things up for you - http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application.

Can I also suggest you rename `IsParent` to just `Parent`, as `IsParent` implies that this is a `Boolean` rather than an entity POCO.

As a final comment, is there a reason to actually have the `Parent`/`IsParent` entity? It seems like once you have the `Member` entity set up with the appropriate navigation properties, you could just use that directly - otherwise you're needlessly adding a wrapper which is just going to add to your confusion.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate direction

Comment: No problem - let me know if you need more code samples or anything.